# How to get JSON as Response in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc

I am trying to return response as JSON. 
After searching I found solution to add headers = "Accept=application/json" in RequestMapping. 
But still it is not working .
It is throwing error **HTTP Status 406 "The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers."**
Here is my controller code :

```
@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier(value = "employeeService")
    public void setEmployeeService(EmployeeService employeeService){
        this.employeeService = employeeService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String test(){
        return "{\"name\":\"xyz\"}";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/employees",method = RequestMethod.GET,headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public  List<Employee> listEmployees(){
        List<Employee> employees = this.employeeService.getEmployees();
        return employees;
    }
}
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: What problem did you have before adding headers = "Accept=application/json" ?

Comment: I think what you might be looking for is "produces" / "consumes" depending if you wanna receive or produce the json data. Here you can read about this: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html

Comment: For example: RequestMapping(
   value = "/api", 
   method = RequestMethod.GET,
   produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)

Comment: Please provide an [mcve]. Also show us what URL you're sending the request to.

Comment: Thanks everyone this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28820028/6497665) worked for me :)

Answer (score 2):

The simple way to generate JSON, XML response is @ResponseBody annotation.

```
@RequestMapping(value =" /jsonPostSingle", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 @ResponseBody
 public PostModel generateJSONPostsingle(@ModelAttribute("postModel") PostModel postModel) {

 if(postModel.getPostId() == 1) {
 postModel.setTitle("post title for id 1");
 } else {
 postModel.setTitle("default post title");
 }
 return postModel;
 }
```

This way you will be able to map your request to model class using @ModelAttribute.

Follow the complete tutorial [Spring MVC : JSON response using @ResponseBody](http://www.ashtpoint.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-json-response-using-responsebody-annotation.html)

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you're trying to send a response from GET request of /employees.

if you are using Spring 3.1, try to use

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/employees",method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
```

instead of adding `headers = "Accept=application/json"`

More info: 
if you want to specify type of data that will send with a request, you can use **consumes** attribute

example:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/foo", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
```

this will consumes and response with JSON type only

check this link about spring update http://spring.io/blog/2011/06/13/spring-3-1-m2-spring-mvc-enhancements/

Hope it helps

Comment: Not sure why everyone is reposting my answer?

Comment: regards, I opened this question and typed the answer without noticing that you were commenting on the post. I just knew when the I added the answer and page is reloaded. @Alex Karlsson

Comment: @Alex you didn't post an answer. You commented on the question.

Comment: Why do you think the `produces` will behave differently than the `headers`?

Comment: Honestly, I just know that it is updated about the syntax but it can produces response with specific type to the user. Anyway, I found the well-described answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31120175/7731765). you can check it out :) @Sotirios Delimanolis

Comment: @AimeTPGM  Hey Aime, I tried every possible suggestion but still it is not working giving HTTP Status 406 and if I am adding consumes ="application/json" then it gives HTTP Status 415. I am using spring 4.1.6 version.

Comment: @Badman could you provide your http request code with its header? did you try to send request from POSTMAN?

Comment: **406** -> the response type is not matched/provided with Accept HTTP header in your Client request. (See [HTTP Headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields))

Comment: **415** -> The request entity has a media type which the server or resource does not support. I saw you are using GET/DELETE, there is no need to use _consumes_ attribute but I just provided that information if it will be useful for you in the future when you're going to have POST/PUT :) [More about HTTP error code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)